# Perforce - finding files which are modified, added or deleted

Tags: perforce

For maintaining the quality of our perforce depot, I would like to find file which were modified, added or deleted over a certain period of time - say over last week. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way of expressing a date as "@now-7days".

But given this date, you could try to count the lines returned by:

```
p4 files //...@yyyy/mm/dd,@now
```

Answer (score 1):

`p4 fstat -T "headModTime" FILENAME` will get you the time that the head revision of that file was modified.  Not entirely sure what format that is in - is it seconds since epoch?

Comment: Yes, that is seconds since epoch.